# WPF vector graphic as DrawingImage StaticResource not visible from a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, vector-graphics, staticresource

In our WPF app we have a bunch of vector graphics for icons in buttons.  We set the ImageSource as a StaticResource on the button style as follows.  The vector itself is created using DrawingImage.

Everything works fine unless the buttons are in a DataTemplate for any kind of ItemsControl bound to a list.  In that case the buttons are perfectly functional but the DrawingImage is not visible.

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="MyIconVector}" x:Shared="False">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 0,8 L 8,0 L 16,8" FillRule="EvenOdd"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Thickness="1.5" Brush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:ImageButton}, FallbackValue=Black}" LineJoin="Round" EndLineCap="Round" StartLineCap="Round"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ImageButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageOnlyButton}">
    <Setter Property="ImageMaxHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="ImageMaxWidth" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{StaticResource MyIconVector}"/>
</Style>
```

Then a simple listbox control as follows and the buttons will be empty.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:ImageButton Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the sample vector above is not truly indicative of my case.  I tried to snag a simpler example for brevity.  Imagine it looks more like this, with PriorityBindings.

It turns out we had an issue with these PriorityBindings.  Removing them and using a standard Pen binding (as in my original post), solves the problem.

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="ExpandIcon" x:Shared="False">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 0,9.5 L 0,16 6.5,16 M 0,16 L 6.5,9.5 M 9.5,0 L 16,0 16,6.5 M 16,0 L 9.5,6.5" FillRule="EvenOdd"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Thickness="1.5" LineJoin="Round" EndLineCap="Round" StartLineCap="Round">
                    <Pen.Brush>
                        <PriorityBinding>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:ImageButton}" Path="Foreground"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:ImageToggleButton}" Path="Foreground" FallbackValue="Black"/>
                        </PriorityBinding>
                    </Pen.Brush>
                </Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```